# Threejs/React-Three-Fiber Animation Reset Thumbnail Keyframe

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I am making an animation in `react-three-fiber` that plays 1 repetition and then resets correctly. However, when it is interrupted midway through, the default/resting/thumbnail keyframe changes to the place where the animation was interrupted. The animation still works, it's just where it resets to that's incorrect. Is there a way to reset this default keyframe to the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround, but a I hope somebody else has a better answer:

```
actions['key'].stop().play()
actions['key'].paused = true
```

Basically, if you play and then pause it immediately, the animation will be on the first frame